# How to setup a cron job in Cpanel to move a file to another directory on the server and rename it

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a server backup .tar.gz file that I need to automate it's move to another folder, and rename it to a name I can use to later download it via ftp (I can't use wildcard to download the file so I have to know the name in order to grab it). I have the other pieces straighten out, I just need to know how/what my cron job script should look like. Can I do this via PHP? or do I need something else?
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: This can be done with php. Sorry, no time write the code.  But if you write code that list the files in a directory, grabs the latest, renames/moves (same thing) - that would be it. Save that script as php and have a cron job ping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question with some help from @ssaltman above, I did it in PHP and used the following code:

```
<?php
rename(reset(glob("/exist/path/*.tar.gz")), "/new/path/NEWNAME.tar.gz");
?>
```

I then attached it to a cron job in cpanel.